# postgres regular expression - extract magnitude level number from string

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column in a postgresql table with strings that contain the magnitude level of an historical list of earthquakes and I need to extract only the number in a separate column.
All values have the following pattern:

[Charater "M" or "Md"][space][**magnitude level number**][" - "][timestamp]

I need to extract only the number but I'm not able to write a specific regular expression to do that, can you help me ? Thanks in advance

```
+───────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+
| Start column                      | Desired output  |
+───────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+
| Md 2.7 - 1985-04-18 20:18:02 UTC  | 2.7             |
| M 2.4 - 1985-04-18 17:49:13 UTC   | 2.4             |
+───────────────────────────────────+─────────────────+
```

Comment: Use this regexp: `'^Md? (\d+\.\d+) '`. See [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mqnLJyMUdKwPWkLHCJKK7b/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/bMnF3k/1

If think this can work 
`(?<= )(?:\b\d\.\d\b|\b\d\d\b|\b\d\b)(?= )`